# Find VC dimension of 1D data

Tags: classifier, vc-theory

```
Consider a data setup of one-dimensional data ∈ R1, where the hypothesis space H is parametrized by {p,q} where x is classified as 1 iff p < x < q.

What will be the VC(H)?
```

Here's my approach:
Since 1D data so we can represent the hypothesis space in a number line.

We will consider 2 points and try all possibilities and see if they can all be classified correctly.

Assume data points are d1 and d2.

**case1**: p < (d1, d2) < q

**case2**: d1 <= p and p < d2 < q

**case3**: p < d1 < q and q >= d2

**case4**: d1 <= p and q >= d2

In all the above cases we can correctly classify.

Let's now take 3 points and try to find a labelling order when it is not possible to classify using a line/hyperplane.

> Assume data points are d1, d2, and d3.
>
> d1 <= p, p < d2 < q, and q >= d3

In the above case, it is not possible to classify using a hyperplane.
Hence, **VC(H) = 2**.

Please let me know if my thinking process is correct.